# Predicate logic: "the product of any four consecutive natural numbers is equal to some perfect square minus 1"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

My task is to rewrite the claim

> The product of any four consecutive natural numbers is equal to some perfect square minus 1

Is the statement I have written accurate?
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N,\ \exists x\in\Bbb N,\ ((n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=x)\implies(\exists y\in\Bbb N,\ x=y^2-1)$$

I'd appreciate any advice regarding my answer.

Comment: You don't need both $x$ and $y$, really. Why not just $$\forall n\in\Bbb N \ \exists x\in\Bbb N : \ (n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=x^2 -1$$

Comment: Would I need to separate the quantifiers with a comma? And could I replace the colon with a comma and put brackets around the following statement?

Comment: You don't need commas, the quantifiers themselves indicate that the next step is starting. The colon is necessary since it means "such that". The parantheses are possible but not necessary: The whole point is to write as little as possible (really: to be concise) and hence I personally wouldn't use them

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this one:

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N,\ \exists x\in\Bbb N,\ ((n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=x)$$

It's actually true: it's sufficient to take $x=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.

Then, your $$\exists y\in\Bbb N,\ x=y^2-1$$
doesn't give a sense to $x$.

Perhaps what you wanted to write is:

$$\forall x\in\Bbb N(\ \exists n\in\Bbb N,\ ((n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=x)\implies(\exists y\in\Bbb N,\ x=y^2-1))$$

which is also a correct answer, a bit longer than the one proposed by Sebastien Shutz.